# keyboard shortcut to throw active window to other monitor

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

I have two monitors.  Windows XP.  NVIDIA video driver. 
I'd like to be able to throw an active window to the other monitor with a keystroke.
The instructions say "open NVIDIA control panel and find the place to define user keystrokes", but I can find no such item in the control panel (or in the nview application).
Does anyone know how to do this?

I'm considering downloading ultramon or multimon as a way around this.  Does anyone have experience with either of these?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked you've got the latest and greatest version of nView installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Windows 7 this function has been provided by the OS.

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>►</kbd> : Move focused window right a screen.

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>◄</kbd> : Move focused window left a screen.

These functions will wrap around, thus if you only have two screens you'll not notice a difference between both functions.

Comment: It's just Win + arrow, no shift needed.

Comment: I just gave it a go without the 'Shift' and it's resulting in window maximizing vertically along the side of the screen it's currently on. Adding the 'Shift' will move the window to the next screen keeping it's dimensions and position.

Comment: My mistake, did not see the question. Very handy to know of this additional function.

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this on XP using [UltraMon's](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) ability to assign such shortcuts

[image]

Comment: No problem - it nicely resizes the window relative the the different sizes of your monitors too; very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is [WinSplit Revolution](http://winsplit-revolution.com/), which gives similar short cuts to throw windows around the screen or to a second monitor. I've used it for years and would recommend it.

[image]